# how to get distance between points using latitude and longitude using php?

Tags: php, google-maps

I am trying to get distance between two location.

Here one location is user input and another location is my store location.
I want to show the the distance between there input location to my store location.

To get user location we use form, where user share there zip code and we convert that zip to longitude and latitude. And in my data base i stored the store location and its respective longitude and latitude.

Here in this case can any one help me to get distance.

Thanks

Comment: Have you googled? What have you tried from what you have found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GeoDataSource](https://www.geodatasource.com/) team develop a very useful function to achieve this:

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
    return ($miles * 1.609344);
  } else if ($unit == "N") {
      return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
      }
}

echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") . " Miles<br>";
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "K") . " Kilometers<br>";
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "N") . " Nautical Miles<br>";
```

[Reference](http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/php)

Comment: Use php `round()` function for that

Comment: Why result is not same as google map distance matrix?

Comment: This will be a rough distance as the crow flys